# "no operator >> matches these operands"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a complete noob at C++, and the first problem I am encountering is the following:

> no operator >> matches these operands

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world!";
    cin >> "hello world!";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the line `cin >> "hello world!";` to do?

Comment: haha, im stupid. I thought you had to put in a string just like python but you don't ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) needs to *write* to a variable, but you are passing it a `const char[13]` string literal instead.

You need to pass it something like a `std::string` instead:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
```

P.S. This is a good time to a) read compiler messages, b) avoid `using namespace std;` globally, c) get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).